# What are advantages of using Sphinx as a search engine for data in a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, search, sphinx

I've liked the idea of using PostgreSQL's built-in text search features to keep my database queries and search queries all in one place.

But are there advantages to using a dedicated search engine and indexer -- and Sphinx in particular -- that I might be missing if I rely solely on Postgres's native search facilities? What are they?

Comment: The capabilities and features of the built-in full text search are probably not as sophisticated as those of a specialized solution. If the built-in FTS is enough for you, then there shouldn't be a need to use an external solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the moment being Sphinx is faster, as it is a specialized system.

On the other hand, PostgreSQL is also evolving. Take a look at [this message](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/5075BF57.9010602@hathawaymix.org) from Oleg Bartunov, announcing coming performance improvements to the FTS. And this is [the presentation](http://wiki.postgresql.org/images/2/25/Full-text_search_in_PostgreSQL_in_milliseconds-extended-version.pdf) that was given by him on the latest PostgreSQL conference in Prague.

Just look through and decide whether your projects fits into the planned delivery terms, according to the info I can find these changes will be available in 9.3, which is planned “sometime” around comming summer.